# How to generate random key separated by hypen

Tags: php, random, yii

I am working on Yii. I want to generate 20 digit random keys. I had written a function as -

```
public function GenerateKey()
{
    //for generating random confirm key
     $length = 20;
     $chars = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A','Z'));
     shuffle($chars);
     $password = implode(array_slice($chars, 0, $length));
     return $password;
}
```

This function is generating 20 digit key correctly. But I want the key in a format like
"g12a-Gh45-gjk7-nbj8-lhk8". i.e. separated by hypen. So what changes do I need to do?

Comment: Do you really want to never use the same character twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) to add the hyphens. [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is used to remove the trailing hyphen it adds, leaving only those hyphens that actually separate groups.

```
return substr(chunk_split($password, 4, '-'), 0, 24);
```

However, note that [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) not only uses a [relatively poor PRNG](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) but also will not allow the same character to be used twice. Instead, use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) in a for loop, and then using chunk_split() is easy to avoid:

```
$password = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if ( $i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0 ) { // nonzero and divisible by 4
        $password .= '-';
    }
    $password .= $chars[mt_rand(0, count($chars) - 1)];
}
return $password;
```

(Even mt_rand() is not a cryptographically secure PRNG. If you need to generate something that must be *extremely* hard to predict (e.g. an encryption key or password reset token), use [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to generate bytes and then a separate function such as [bin2hex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) to encode them into printable characters. I am not familiar with Yii, so I cannot say whether or not it has a function for this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Yii internal function:

```
Yii::app()->getSecurityManager()->generateRandomString($length);
```